# Search questions by relative time of creation

Tags: feature-request, search, low-quality-posts

I'd like filter out recently created questions, e.g., those created within the last 2 hours. (My reason is below.)

The related date search parameter does something like that: `created:..1d` restricts the search to the questions that were created no later than yesterday (using UTC).

I propose adding a similar parameter for *hours*: e.g., `created:..2h`  for questions that were asked at least two hours ago.

---

[Inspiration for this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/3717023):

> Do not fight silly questions!... Have them answered, all right, but just take them out of the way

I get tired of wading through trivial questions. Since most of them get answered quickly, restricting the search to `created:..2h answers:0` would help filter out the fluff.